exponential map of lie groups
In "A micro Lie theory for state estimation in robotics" by Joan Sola`, there is a formular on page 6:
$$\exp((t+s)τ^∧) = exp(tτ^∧)exp(sτ^∧)    \quad (17)$$
And another one on page 10:
$$Exp(τ +δτ)≈Exp(τ)Exp(Jr(τ)δτ) \quad (68)$$
However, I am not sure where is wrong in the following derivation I have in mind:
$$Exp(τ +δτ) = exp((1+δ)τ^∧) = exp(τ^∧)exp(δτ^∧)) = Exp(τ)Exp(δτ) $$
if the derivation is right, then why the approximate in formular (68) above and the Jr(τ) term?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Your book is using some nonstandard notation, you should explain it. I also suggest learning basics of the theory of Lie groups from a different source (there are many suggestions of textbooks that you can find on this site).
